# Array.push() not working return null array after push

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I am using Vue project to my mini search system and its database is firebase. I would like to know if these is a language error or its library error. where the Array.push() is not working properly.

I could show only screen shot because it could not show in other reproduction when I reproduce the code.

```
let trainVal1 = []
  for(let n in dataTrainingVal) {
    console.log({key: n, ...dataTrainingVal[n]})
    trainVal1.push({key: n, ...dataTrainingVal[n]})
    console.log(trainVal1)
  }
```

[image]

thanks!

Comment: looks like the array is fine - what do you think is wrong?

Comment: you should show the `dataTrainingVal` structure, i'm not sure if is a object or array

Comment: I seem fine, just make sure that you are doing in correct point, try use `console.log('MY ARRAY', trainVal1)` instead of `console.log(trainVal1)`

Comment: Actually your console log statement proofs that array push works correctly - it is just that you later empty the array - console log keeps the reference and you only see it empty then. To convince you use a copy `console.log(array.slice())`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a object for the `{key: n, ...dataTrainingVal[n]}` like `var obj = {key: n, ...dataTrainingVal[n]}`. Then push it.

```
var trainVal1 = []
  for(let n in dataTrainingVal) {
    var obj = {key: n, ...dataTrainingVal[n]}
    trainVal1.push(obj)
    console.log(trainVal1)
  }
```

try also **var** insted of **let**

Answer (score 0):

you should change your code like below

```
let trainVal1 = []
  for(let n = 0; n < dataTrainingVal.length; n++) {
    console.log({key: n, data:dataTrainingVal[n]})
    trainVal1.push({key: n, data:dataTrainingVal[n]})
    console.log(trainVal1)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is on the spread operator section. I have updated your code to a working solution.

```js
let trainVal1 = []

let dataTrainingVal = [1,2,3]

for(let n in dataTrainingVal) {
    console.log(dataTrainingVal[n])
    trainVal1.push({key: n, val: dataTrainingVal[n]})
    console.log(trainVal1)
  }
```

Please note: Do not use for in loop for array iterations.

> Note: for...in should not be used to iterate over an Array where the index order is important.  [Read More on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine... the only missing piece is defining dataTrainingVal.

```
     let trainVal = []
       let dataTrainingVal = {firstname: 'Pedro', lastName: 'Juan'}
       for(let n in dataTrainingVal) {
          console.log({key: n, ...dataTrainingVal[n]})
          trainVal.push({key: n, ...dataTrainingVal[n]})
          console.log(trainVal)
       }
```

The o/p :

(2) [{…}, {…}]

0: {0: "P", 1: "e", 2: "d", 3: "r", 4: "o", key: "firstname"}

1: {0: "J", 1: "u", 2: "a", 3: "n", key: "lastName"}

length: 2